# Sockets not communicate even if no exception are launched

Tags: java, string, sockets, reader

I'm trying to send a string from the client to the server, but even if all the code compiles without errors and no exception are thrown, nothing is sent. This is my server:

```
        String nomeAccount = "";
        try {
            //PHASE 1: The server receives the email
            try {
                InputStream inStream = incoming.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream()));
                //if I print something here it works
                nomeAccount = in.readLine(); 
                //here nothing get printed
                System.out.println("Nome: "+nomeAccount);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Not works");
                Logger.getLogger(ServerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    incoming.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Not works");
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
```

This is the client:

```
//PHASE 1: The client sends a string to the server
    try {
        InputStream inStream = s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outStream = s.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream, true);
        out.write(account+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems are

- PrintWriter eats any Exceptions throws. You wouldn't see them if they were thrown.
- The purpose of using `PrintWriter` instead of a plain `Writer` is to use `println`, `print` or `printf`
- unless you print a new line it won't flush the data (which should work with write() but println is clearer)